# Can OSR-compiled methods be used by a subsequent call?

Tags: java, performance, jvm, jit, jvm-hotspot

I understand how [on-stack replacement](http://www.cliffc.org/blog/2011/11/22/what-the-heck-is-osr-and-why-is-it-bad-or-good/) (OSR) generally works, but what I don't understand is whether an OSR compiled method is ever useful once the method leaves the initial invocation that triggered the compilation - can the JITed code be used on a subsequent iteration?

It seems like it could, once the interpreter proceeds to the same bytecode index that the old OSR kicked off at it could again enter the OSR-compiled method.

I'm asking mostly because I'm seeing a case where Hotspot immediately OSR compiles my method twice (for different BCIs), but doesn't even do a normal C2 non-OSR compile until it has been running for a couple of minutes (despite a million calls or more to the method). So I'm wondering if it is using the OSR C2 method in the meantime (there is also a non-OSR C1 method)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they can be reused. But only at the same bytecode index they were generated for, and only in response to back branch event of the compilation policy.

HotSpot `InstanceKlass` structure (an internal representation of Java class) keeps a [list of OSR methods](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/812ed44725b8/src/share/vm/oops/instanceKlass.hpp#l251) for the class. Whenever a compilation is requested, CompileBroker [looks for](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/hotspot/file/812ed44725b8/src/share/vm/compiler/compileBroker.cpp#l1370) an existing NMethod in this list.

I can't tell much about your particular case without a closer look, but from the given description I suspect that your application calls C1-compiled version. Method's entry point is never set to OSR-compiled NMethod.

Comment: Yes, and in the end I didn't reproduce it - later runs mostly showed the hot method getting a normal non-OSR C2 (level 4) compile within a second or so after startup, so I'm not sure what was up. Perhaps it was a glitch in the LogCompilation output (e.g., clobbered by PrintAssembly concurrently writing?) because the _timing_ seemed to indicate it was running OK.

Comment: Did you mean "at the same bytecode **index** they were generated for..." above?